# System.Management.ManagementException: 'Invalid query '

Tags: c#, windows, user-permissions

I have a function to check whether Windows Defender Real Time is enabled or disabled which is as follows

```
public static bool GetRealTimeProtectionStatus()
        {
            bool enabled = false;

            string path = @"Root\Microsoft\Windows\Defender";
            string className = "MSFT_MpPreference";

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"SELECT * FROM {className} WHERE Path='{path}'"))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    // قراءة قيمة التفعيل
                    int realTimeScanDirection = (int)obj.GetPropertyValue("RealTimeScanDirection");
                    enabled = (realTimeScanDirection == 1);

                    break;
                }
            }

            return enabled;
        }
```

But at the line

```
foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
```

I am getting the following error

```
System.Management.ManagementException: 'Invalid query '
```

I expected that the program might need permission to check and change Windows Defender Real Time, so I ran the program by giving it system administrator privileges, but that did not work for me.

Comment: Did you check if escaping of '\' works as intended?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain with an example?